# Can a 2W supply power the Relays

Tags: power-supply, power, relay

I'm designing my first circuit with 2 relays `JQX-15F / 005-1Z1 NO20A/NC10A 240VAC`([datasheet](http://www.bcrelays.com/Relay.JQX-15F.pdf), probably the `SPDT` variant) and a 2W 5V power supply. Reading the datasheet I could not figure out how much power is needed to operate the relay.

Is 0.9W (coil dissipation) the power required to power on 1 relay? If so, a 2W power supply should be sufficient to power 2 of these relays.

Additionally, is it necessary to have 100uF decoupling capacitors across the relay's power inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a diode connected reversed biased across the relay's coil pins.  This will remove any back-EMF spikes.  A Schottky diode is best as it reacts fast to the change in current direction.

The big question is what is the current rating of the power supply?  The current of the relay is listed in the data sheet as 185mA, so two relays would require 370mA.  At 5V that would equate to 1.85W. so roughly what the "coil dissipation" states (times 2).

The 2W of the power supply might be in the input, or it might be the output rating.  If it is the output rating then I would expect the current limit of the power supply to be listed as 400mA.

So yes, that should be able to power it, but it doesn't give you much headroom.  Personally I always like to derate a little whenever possible.  Not only does it give you some extra room to play with, but it can also extend the lifetime of the component / device if you aren't pushing it too close to its max.  So I'd be inclined to go for a power supply that was 500mA (2.5W) rather than 400mA, but that's just me.

Comment: Yes, note the Norminal current (yes, it says Norminal, maybe it should be a new word) is +/- 10%.  If you get a couple of relays with 10% high coil currents your 2W supply will not cut it.